# Login immediately after signup

Tags: laravel-4

This way I store user information to DB:

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = $arr['email'];
$user->nick = $arr['display'];
$user->ip = Request::getClientIp();
$user->save();
```

and it does its work nicely but after `save()` method I'm going to log in the user this way:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

It never result in a true condition. Then I tried to log the user with his ID, when I dump the `$user`:

```
object(User)#179 (20) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["table":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "myemail@gmail.com"
    ["nick"]=>
    string(17) "my_name"
    ["ip"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-01-25 09:48:07"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2014-01-25 09:48:07"
    ["id"]=>
    int(13)
  }
.
.
.
```

Then I tried this:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user->original['id']);
```

Actually `$user->original['id']` doesn return `NULL`!

Helps are appreciated!

Comment: Show your `User` model, BTW, `Auth::login($user)` is the right way.

Comment: The `User` model must implement interface `Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface` did you do it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera Yes, authentication will done if user login from login form manually. User model is as original as the one laravel has.

Comment: So, you can't login using `Auth::login($user)` ?

Comment: For testing only, make sure this works, `$user = User::find(1);
 Auth::login($user);
 return Redirect::to('/');`

Comment: @SheikhHeera No it doesn't log the user this way but it works on another method for logging based on user inputs.

Comment: The code works on my `localhost`, just tested this. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera If I knew the problem I wouldn't ask it here, but I'm logging the user immediately after Oauth v2 authentication, I store email and nick name in database.

Comment: You are using `Oauth` ? Do you have `user id` after you save the user in `DB` if you have the `id` then try using `$user = User::find(id);Auth::login($user)`, Something could be wrong with `Oauth` integration, because normally it works, tested.

Comment: @SheikhHeera on RESTful controllers can we define a method like `getDashboardEdit()` and access it via `localhost/users/dashboard/edit`?

Comment: Yes, you can add any method manually.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I mean about routing. getDashboardEdit will produce dashbaord/edit route?

Comment: Yes, it's normally possible if the generated route is being used. To clarify yourself what route you have for the controller you may run `php artisan routes` from `terminal/command prompt` so you can see what route is mapped to what method.